# Prometheus metric for over time not working

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-operator

I need to create a prometheus query that bring the numbers of event in one hour and / on day

when run the following and run request I see that the number increased as expected , 5 api calls the counter raised in 5.

this is the basic query `vector_component_sent_events_total`

Now I tried the following to get the number of requests for one hour but I get wrong numbers (like 0.0.5 which is not the number of request that I send in 1 hour...)

I tried the following, what am I missing here?

`sum(rate(vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"}[1h]))`

I got something like   `0.004201679495327872` , but I send only 5 (or bit more) request in hour ... any idea?

https://vector.dev/docs/administration/monitoring/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an increase in your metric for 1 hour you could use this:

```
increase(vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"}[1h])
```

Notice also, this clause in [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) of `increase` function:

> The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments.

If you want an exact integer increase, you can either use [`round`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#round) on the result of `increase`, or use some workarounds.

One such workaround is using subtraction with `offset` operator

```
vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"}
 - vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"} offset 1h
```

this has a significant drawback: violently incorrect results near counter resets.

A bit more correct result near resets might produce query

```
vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"}
 - vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"} offset 1h >= 0
or round(increase(vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="ta", job="nt"}[1h]))
```

It will count "increase" based on subtraction outside of resets, and fallback to rounding of `increase` call near resets.

*CAUTION:* Please remember, this is a hack and it could produce incorrect data in some circumstances.

Comment: thanks you, 1+ , when I use increase I see something like `15.0078165711308
` , why, I expect it to be only `15` , this number of requests, any idea and how to avoid that?

Comment: @PeterSO, This behaviour is [documented](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) and you could not avoid it when using `increase`. I added a sketchy workaround to get "the best of both worlds": integer delta from `offset` and continuity from `increase`, but it should be used only for rarely resettable counters.

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain myself well, I need the most accurate data and not comprise on it, to verify, you are suggesting to use the `increase` and ignore the numbers after the dots, am I right? btw what are those number `.0078165711308` ?

Comment: @PeterSO, `increase` will produce **mostly** correct values **at any time** (with rather small discrepancies). These discrepancies are a result of the inner workings of `increase`: more about it you could read in the documentation linked above and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665904/why-does-increase-return-a-value-of-1-33-in-prometheus). `offset` will produce **exact** values **most of the time**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would be great if you can edit the answer about what you recommended most as its a bit unclear as I understand that the last example could be not accurate

Comment: Those are three valid alternatives. And sadly, each of them has its own pitfalls. Anybody who sees this answer should decide what query to use by themselves.

Comment: As I need the `most accurate numbers` i've decided to use the following `floor(sum(increase(vector_component_sent_events_total{component_id="tra", job="ant"}[24])))` and it gives the exact numbers but didnt test it heavily, WDYT?

Comment: Use `round()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `sum(rate(m[d]))` doesn't return the increase of `m` over the duration `d`. It returns the summary **average** increase rate over the lookbehind window `d` for all the [counter metrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) `m`:

- The [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function returns the **average** increase rate over the specified lookbehind window in square brackets.
- The [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function returns the sum over multiple input time series.

If you need obtaining the increase for [counter metric](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) over the last hour (see `1h` in square brackets), then use the following query:

```
increase(vector_component_sent_events_total[1h])
```

This query uses [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function for calculating the increase of the provided counter over the specified time range in square brackets. This function calculates the increase individually per each input time series.

If you need summary increase over the last hour for multiple time series, then wrap the query above into [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum):

```
sum(increase(vector_component_sent_events_total[1h]))
```

Prometheus may return fractional or incomplete results from [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) over integer counter because of the following issues:

- [Extrapolation issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746).
- Prometheus ignores the increase between the last raw sample just before the lookbehind window passed to `increase()` in square brackets and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window.

If you need exact `m` counter increase over some duration `d`, then `m - (m offset d)` query may work. But it returns incorrect results in the following cases:

- When `m` [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) resets to zero on the given lookbehind window `d`. This usually happens on the restart of the application, which exports the counter metric.
- When some counter matching `m` appears inside the lookbehind window `d`. This usually happens when new entity with the associated counter appears in the application.

Prometheus doesn't provide working solution for these issues :(

P.S. If you still want consistently obtaining **exact** increase for counter metric over some lookbehind window, then try [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. Its' [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function is free from issues mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, we are using Prometheus, does it make sense to run Victoria metrics in addition to Prometheus ? I understand the pros, what are the cons beside we need to install additional helm chart and be responsible of the LCM...

Comment: It is possible to substitute Prometheus with VictoriaMetrics - see [these helm charts](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/helm-charts).