# Grafana panel showing client request count per HTTP status

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I would like to see how many times I get 200, 4xx, 5xx within a selected period of time. The query I managed to write with my limited knowledge is:

`sum(increase(http_client_requests_second_count{uri=~"$apiUri"}[1m])) by (uri, method, status)`

and the result I got is

[image: grafana_panel]

and the result I was hoping to see was 1 for 400 and 18 for CLIENT_ERROR, as seen in Prometheus:

[image: prometheus_query]

What would be the correct query?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you show different data.

Prometheus' web ui screenshot shows plain metric `http_client_requests_second_count` which is is the total number of requests  made to endpoint in labels (counting from previous reset - most likely restart of application).

Grafana's screenshot shows result of mentioned query. And this query gets number of requests to server for the last one minute aggregated by `uri`, `method`, and `status` of request/response.

And if you want to see number of request per HTTP status (for the last minute) you 'll need similar query:

```
sum(increase(http_client_requests_second_count{uri=~"$apiUri"}[1m])) by (status)
```

Or

```
sum(http_client_requests_second_count{uri=~"$apiUri"} - http_client_requests_second_count{uri=~"$apiUri"} offset 1m) by (status)
```

if you want integer numbers (and don't mind negatives near restarts of app)

`metric - metric offset 1m` counts difference between current value of metric and its value 1 minute ago. It produces integer result (for integer metrics), while `increase()` could produce float (due to nature of inner working of `increase()`). But near resets this query will produce negative values (because it's plain subtraction), while `increase()` will produce correct approximation near resets too.

Comment: thanks, can you perhaps explain the last query a bit?

Comment: @asli, sure: added some explanation on how `metric - metric offset 1m` works. Additionally, you could see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75828166/21363224), where I discussed a bit more on this topic.

Comment: @asli, completely forgot to mention: if you are not planning to use Graph mode: Area in your stat panel than switch on option `Instant` for your query, to lower amount of data requested from Prometheus.