# Why prometheus "increase" function on counter shows incorrect values

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am testing prometheus Counter. In below case, 10 has been added to the counter, so the value changed from 14 to 24. But when using the increase function, it doesn't show "10", but shows "12" instead.

[No function applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9uW1.png)

[image: Applied increase function]
[image: No function applied]

Comment: ["The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments."](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grafana panel showing client request count per HTTP status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75929696/grafana-panel-showing-client-request-count-per-http-status)