# How to solve margin of error in Grafana with increase()

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to get this metric from prometheus:

```
sum by(pod) (increase(application_input_total{service="$service"}[1m]))
```

It is somewhat working, but it has an margin of error in it. This metric shows the amount of requests that our Java application receives. When I do 1 call with Postman, Grafana shows it as 1,09 calls. When I do 20 calls, Grafana shows 22, 60 calls shows 67 in GF and so on. The higher the calls the bigger the difference get.

Someone knows how to solve this? I think it has something to do with the [1m] or with the Prometheus configuration, but not sure what it could be.

Comment: No, this is expected behavior of increase. [The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments.](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase)

Comment: Afaik, there is no universally good answer how this can be avoided. One of many attempts to explain this and and provide some workarounds you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75828166/21363224). More generally - google it, its popular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus may return non-integer result from `increase()` over integer [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) because of extrapolation. Additionally, Prometheus may miss a part of counter increase between the last raw sample just before the specified interval in square brackets and the first raw sample inside the interval. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) and [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit) for details.

If you want obtaining the expected integer results from `increase()` function without extrapolation and missing calculations, then try [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html). It works like PromQL, but its' `increase()` function returns the expected results without issues mentioned above.