# Fractional values in Grafana with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana

world!
Is it possible to display incremental values only as integer, and never fractional values?
I have integer counters in Prometheus, (reading period 10s), apply operation `increase(<expr>[$__rate_interval])`, refresh rate in grafana 10s. And I'm getting fractional values like 1.2

Yes, there is tooltip in Grafana: `it is possible to get a non-integer result`. 
But is it possible to fix this in anyway to always getting integer values only?

Comment: This is (documented) quirk of Prometheus' increase function. You can simply apply `round` function to get integer if you want, but there is a room for some error there. This is a well known problem with no ideal solution. Here is one of discussion around answer to similar question, they might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75828166/21363224

Comment: @markalex solution by the link works great, thanks! Although I didn't understand part with ` or increase(metrics_name[$__interval])` it haven't changed anything in my case

Comment: It insures that you'll get results near resets, if restart of application will take some time. Because if either part of subtraction doesn't exists - Prometheus will not return result. In that case `or` will fall back to `increase`

Comment: @markalex I've reread again, experimented and yes `>=0 or ...` part is required when counter has been reset. Thanks a lot, this solved the problem completely! )