# How increase function in promql is calculated?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I have promql query

```
aggregator_unavailable_apiservice_total
```

Which is giving following data in grafana when I ran query in grafana. Please find the provided screenshot.
[image]

After using this query I am getting the following data. Provided in the screenshot

```
increase(aggregator_unavailable_apiservice_total[10m])
```

[image]

1. In first the value got increased from 5 to 9. After applying increase function to same metric with 10m. I am seeing the value 4.44. How the value 4.44 is calculated?
2. Why aggregator_unavailable_apiservice_total is showing always some value even though apiserver is up?

Please help me in understanding the "increase" function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple unrelated questions in one post: this is a ground for closure of question as unfocused.

Comment: Regarding first part: [official documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) for function `increase` states: *The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments.* You can find some approaches to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75825765/21363224)

Comment: And regarding second part: that's how counters supposed to work. If nothing is happening it exposes the same value. If value counter represents changed - counter increases accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @markalex. You explained me all the queries.